Identifying 4-connected point patterns in a grid of 3D points with noise
I have a set of points in 3D space represented by the following NumPy array:
import numpy as np
points = np.array([4.5403791090466825, -6.474122845743137, 1.720865155131852
                   4.544710813420152, -6.224218513611945, 1.7088861199877527
                   4.537233620491136, -5.98484530658863, 1.699488873354222
                   4.521937968342778, -5.721674150789189, 1.6849114580360904
                   4.4999241714099405, -5.4938430240669724, 1.679752942910385
                   4.830182546259025, -5.657936979701614, 1.6888307295378522
                   5.121468843368871, -5.803097135994744, 1.6954809688529893
                   5.439088364842268, -5.965512825953125, 1.6981638740242355
                   5.704276912211997, -6.100013441509505, 1.69575210534024
                   5.674604213881624, -6.316464211693753, 1.696360866592035
                   5.6375373276155125, -6.568875993817544, 1.7173100480278745
                   5.601324312047108, -6.791416283459123, 1.7222351265798983
                   5.556256817028301, -7.025669295257478, 1.7240530742321507
                   5.3173007670429975, -6.898939280431394, 1.7278595480033725
                   5.046628449981028, -6.753703318879904, 1.725804884872875
                   4.803244289601083, -6.620716409453152, 1.726377963879765
                   4.822340852273528, -6.379078541501187, 1.7032476446943
                   4.830532452723338, -6.144069893351172, 1.7047976672875338
                   4.834760563421453, -5.884305796074045, 1.6876475718597206
                   5.110719812888194, -6.028142616316405, 1.687525680260671
                   5.417740311618597, -6.184558989903391, 1.7124527178431916
                   5.385270875729216, -6.438008203433672, 1.712366908533943
                   5.355507693509876, -6.661093026054448, 1.729038450873722
                   5.07348022798482, -6.513010696655368, 1.726279452092121
                   5.090180621637709, -6.283446799878667, 1.7091940453643182])

A plot of these points (and their labels) in 3D space is shown in the image below.
In this image, certain points are circled in red, referred to as the 4-connected points to the point of interest. However, my attempt to solve this problem by finding the closest 4 points (euclidian distance) to the point of interest doesn't work in all cases (points drawn in blue).

It should be noted that the 3D points are contained in a plane or a curved surface. However, the presence of noise in the data readings means that while we can approximate the points to be on or near a surface, they are not precisely on top of it.
Additionally, the grid of points can sometimes be slightly deformed, not forming straight lines, as shown in this cloud of points (raw data).

Do you have any suggestions on how to determine these 4-connected points in 3D space?
Edit 04/04/2024:
Two possible solutions that look very similar in terms of relative angles when the grid is very skewed:


"Four connected points" is not a well-defined concept. As you've seen, it won't always be the four closest points. You need to more carefully define your criteria, and I think they'll probably need to be heuristic criteria. One example that may fit: for all points within a certain distance, choose the four that are closest while still appearing to have relative angles of about 90 degrees.

Thank you for the answer, Reinderien! Following Cyril's answer and approximating the grid to 2D, we end up dealing with parallelograms. I edited my answer to show that using only angles might not be robust enough, because when the grid is very skewed, there are two possible solutions that look the same in terms of angles!

You can approach this in a few separate steps. First, extract a plane of best fit:
import itertools

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy.cluster.vq


def load_points() -> np.ndarray:
    points = np.array((
        (4.5403791090466825, -6.474122845743137, 1.720865155131852 ),
        (4.544710813420152, -6.224218513611945, 1.7088861199877527 ),
        (4.537233620491136, -5.98484530658863, 1.699488873354222   ),
        (4.521937968342778, -5.721674150789189, 1.6849114580360904 ),
        (4.4999241714099405, -5.4938430240669724, 1.679752942910385),
        (4.830182546259025, -5.657936979701614, 1.6888307295378522 ),
        (5.121468843368871, -5.803097135994744, 1.6954809688529893 ),
        (5.439088364842268, -5.965512825953125, 1.6981638740242355 ),
        (5.704276912211997, -6.100013441509505, 1.69575210534024   ),
        (5.674604213881624, -6.316464211693753, 1.696360866592035  ),
        (5.6375373276155125, -6.568875993817544, 1.7173100480278745),
        (5.601324312047108, -6.791416283459123, 1.7222351265798983 ),
        (5.556256817028301, -7.025669295257478, 1.7240530742321507 ),
        (5.3173007670429975, -6.898939280431394, 1.7278595480033725),
        (5.046628449981028, -6.753703318879904, 1.725804884872875  ),
        (4.803244289601083, -6.620716409453152, 1.726377963879765  ),
        (4.822340852273528, -6.379078541501187, 1.7032476446943    ),
        (4.830532452723338, -6.144069893351172, 1.7047976672875338 ),
        (4.834760563421453, -5.884305796074045, 1.6876475718597206 ),
        (5.110719812888194, -6.028142616316405, 1.687525680260671  ),
        (5.417740311618597, -6.184558989903391, 1.7124527178431916 ),
        (5.385270875729216, -6.438008203433672, 1.712366908533943  ),
        (5.355507693509876, -6.661093026054448, 1.729038450873722  ),
        (5.07348022798482, -6.513010696655368, 1.726279452092121   ),
        (5.090180621637709, -6.283446799878667, 1.7091940453643182 ),
    ))
    return points


def plane_fit(points: np.ndarray) -> tuple[np.ndarray, np.ndarray]:
    # Over-determined plane of best fit in form ax + by + cz = 1
    normal, residuals, rank, singular = np.linalg.lstsq(
        a=points, b=np.ones_like(points[:, 0]), rcond=None,
    )

    # Arbitrary reference point in middle of locus, exactly on plane of best fit
    reference_point = np.empty_like(points[0])
    reference_point[:-1] = points[:, :-1].mean(axis=0)
    reference_point[-1] = (
        1 - reference_point[:-1].dot(normal[:-1])
    ) / normal[-1]

    return normal, reference_point


def project_planar_r3(
    points: np.ndarray,
    normal: np.ndarray,
    reference_point: np.ndarray,
) -> np.ndarray:
    # Project points onto plane, still in original xyz coordinate system
    planar = points - np.outer((points - reference_point)@normal, normal)
    return planar


def plot_planar(planar: np.ndarray) -> plt.Figure:
    fig = plt.figure()
    fig.suptitle('Planar projection')
    plt.scatter(planar[:, 0], planar[:, 1])
    return fig


Perform k-means to find where likely offsets are:
def cartesian_neighbours(
    planar: np.ndarray,
    tol: float,
):
    px, py = planar[:, :-1].T
    return np.vstack([
        planar[
              (px > x)
            & (py > y - tol)
            & (px <= x + tol)
            & (py <= y + tol),
            :,
        ] - (x, y, z)
        for x, y, z in planar
    ])


def cluster(neighbours: np.ndarray) -> list:
    codebook, distortion = scipy.cluster.vq.kmeans(
        obs=neighbours, k_or_guess=3,
    )
    return codebook


def plot_neighbours(neighbours: np.ndarray) -> plt.Figure:
    fig = plt.figure()
    fig.suptitle('Neighbour distribution')
    plt.scatter(neighbours[:, 0], neighbours[:, 1], marker='+')
    return fig


Pick two basis vectors from the neighbours. From these, form an affine correction matrix. This is a little involved and I didn't get it working well, but for your current data an affine matrix can look like
np.array((
    (  3.5,  2.1),
    (  0.0,  4.0),
    (  0.0,  0.0),
    (-15.8, 16.4),
))

applied like
corrected = np.hstack((
    planar, np.ones_like(planar[:, :1]),
)) @ affine


These corrected points can then be fairly easily assigned as "connected" based on proximity to integer coordinates.
As an alternative (that still requires a more robust cluster selection heuristic),
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy.cluster.vq


def load_points() -> np.ndarray:
    points = np.array((
        (4.5403791090466825, -6.474122845743137, 1.720865155131852 ),
        (4.544710813420152, -6.224218513611945, 1.7088861199877527 ),
        (4.537233620491136, -5.98484530658863, 1.699488873354222   ),
        (4.521937968342778, -5.721674150789189, 1.6849114580360904 ),
        (4.4999241714099405, -5.4938430240669724, 1.679752942910385),
        (4.830182546259025, -5.657936979701614, 1.6888307295378522 ),
        (5.121468843368871, -5.803097135994744, 1.6954809688529893 ),
        (5.439088364842268, -5.965512825953125, 1.6981638740242355 ),
        (5.704276912211997, -6.100013441509505, 1.69575210534024   ),
        (5.674604213881624, -6.316464211693753, 1.696360866592035  ),
        (5.6375373276155125, -6.568875993817544, 1.7173100480278745),
        (5.601324312047108, -6.791416283459123, 1.7222351265798983 ),
        (5.556256817028301, -7.025669295257478, 1.7240530742321507 ),
        (5.3173007670429975, -6.898939280431394, 1.7278595480033725),
        (5.046628449981028, -6.753703318879904, 1.725804884872875  ),
        (4.803244289601083, -6.620716409453152, 1.726377963879765  ),
        (4.822340852273528, -6.379078541501187, 1.7032476446943    ),
        (4.830532452723338, -6.144069893351172, 1.7047976672875338 ),
        (4.834760563421453, -5.884305796074045, 1.6876475718597206 ),
        (5.110719812888194, -6.028142616316405, 1.687525680260671  ),
        (5.417740311618597, -6.184558989903391, 1.7124527178431916 ),
        (5.385270875729216, -6.438008203433672, 1.712366908533943  ),
        (5.355507693509876, -6.661093026054448, 1.729038450873722  ),
        (5.07348022798482, -6.513010696655368, 1.726279452092121   ),
        (5.090180621637709, -6.283446799878667, 1.7091940453643182 ),
    ))
    return points


def plane_fit(points: np.ndarray) -> tuple[np.ndarray, np.ndarray]:
    # Over-determined plane of best fit in form ax + by + cz = 1
    normal, residuals, rank, singular = np.linalg.lstsq(
        a=points, b=np.ones_like(points[:, 0]), rcond=None,
    )

    # Arbitrary reference point in middle of locus, exactly on plane of best fit
    reference_point = np.empty_like(points[0])
    reference_point[:-1] = points[:, :-1].mean(axis=0)
    reference_point[-1] = (
        1 - reference_point[:-1].dot(normal[:-1])
    ) / normal[-1]

    return normal, reference_point


def project_planar_r3(
    points: np.ndarray,
    normal: np.ndarray,
    reference_point: np.ndarray,
) -> np.ndarray:
    # Project points onto plane, still in original xyz coordinate system
    planar = points - np.outer((points - reference_point)@normal, normal)
    return planar


def plot_planar(planar: np.ndarray, title: str) -> plt.Figure:
    fig = plt.figure()
    fig.suptitle(title)
    plt.scatter(planar[:, 0], planar[:, 1])
    return fig


def cartesian_neighbours(
    planar: np.ndarray, tol: float,
):
    px, py = planar[:, :-1].T
    return np.vstack([
        planar[
              (px > x)
            & (py > y - tol)
            & (px <= x + tol)
            & (py <= y + tol),
            :,
        ] - (x, y, z)
        for x, y, z in planar
    ])


def plot_neighbours(neighbours: np.ndarray, u: np.ndarray, v: np.ndarray) -> plt.Figure:
    fig = plt.figure()
    fig.suptitle('Neighbour distribution')
    plt.scatter(neighbours[:, 0], neighbours[:, 1], marker='+')
    plt.plot(
        [0, u[0]],
        [0, u[1]],
    )
    plt.plot(
        [0, v[0]],
        [0, v[1]],
    )
    return fig


def cluster(neighbours: np.ndarray) -> tuple[
    np.ndarray,  # neighbour centroids, k*3
    np.ndarray,  # label indices, n
]:
    centroids, labels = scipy.cluster.vq.kmeans2(
        data=neighbours, k=8, seed=0,
    )
    return centroids, labels


def deskew_points(
    points: np.ndarray,
    u: np.ndarray,
    v: np.ndarray,
) -> np.ndarray:
    target = points.copy()
    target -= target.min(axis=0)
    de_uv, residuals, rank, singular = np.linalg.lstsq(
        a=np.stack((u, v)), b=np.eye(2), rcond=None,
    )
    target = target @ de_uv
    offset = (
        target[target[:, 0] - target[:, 0].min() < 0.5, 0].mean(),
        target[target[:, 1] - target[:, 1].min() < 0.5, 1].mean(),
    )
    target -= offset
    return target


def affine_from_deskewed(
    points: np.ndarray,
    deskewed: np.ndarray,
) -> np.ndarray:
    deskewed = deskewed.round()

    affine, residuals, rank, singular = np.linalg.lstsq(
        a=np.hstack((
            points,
            np.ones_like(points[:, :1]),
        )),
        b=deskewed, rcond=None,
    )
    return affine


def project_uv(
    points: np.ndarray,
    affine: np.ndarray,
):
    return np.hstack((
        points, np.ones_like(points[:, :1]),
    )) @ affine


def plot_corrected(
    deskewed: np.ndarray,
    corrected: np.ndarray,
) -> plt.Figure:
    fig = plt.figure()
    plt.scatter(*deskewed.T, label='Deskewed')
    plt.scatter(*corrected.T, label='Corrected')
    plt.legend()
    return fig


def main() -> None:
    points = load_points()
    normal, reference_point = plane_fit(points=points)
    print('Planar normal:', normal)
    print('Reference point:', reference_point)

    planar = project_planar_r3(points=points, normal=normal, reference_point=reference_point)
    plot_planar(planar=planar, title='Planar projection')

    neighbours = cartesian_neighbours(planar=planar, tol=0.5)

    centroids, labels = cluster(neighbours)
    print('Neighbour cluster centroids:')
    print(centroids)

    # You'll need to develop a heuristic to choose these neighbour labels
    u_label = 2
    v_label = 7

    u = centroids[u_label]
    v = centroids[v_label]
    print('Inferred basis u, v:')
    print(u)
    print(v)
    plot_neighbours(neighbours=neighbours, u=u, v=v)

    deskewed = deskew_points(points=points, u=u, v=v)

    affine = affine_from_deskewed(points=points, deskewed=deskewed)
    print('Affine correction:')
    print(affine)

    corrected = project_uv(points=points, affine=affine)
    plot_corrected(deskewed=deskewed, corrected=corrected)

    plt.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()



A first way to approach the problem would be to perform dimensionality reduction, and then retrieve the 4 nearest points:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from sklearn.manifold import LocallyLinearEmbedding
from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors

points = np.array([[4.5403791090466825, -6.474122845743137, 1.720865155131852],
                   [4.544710813420152, -6.224218513611945, 1.7088861199877527],
                   [4.537233620491136, -5.98484530658863, 1.699488873354222],
                   [4.521937968342778, -5.721674150789189, 1.6849114580360904],
                   [4.4999241714099405, -5.4938430240669724, 1.679752942910385],
                   [4.830182546259025, -5.657936979701614, 1.6888307295378522],
                   [5.121468843368871, -5.803097135994744, 1.6954809688529893],
                   [5.439088364842268, -5.965512825953125, 1.6981638740242355],
                   [5.704276912211997, -6.100013441509505, 1.69575210534024],
                   [5.674604213881624, -6.316464211693753, 1.696360866592035],
                   [5.6375373276155125, -6.568875993817544, 1.7173100480278745],
                   [5.601324312047108, -6.791416283459123, 1.7222351265798983],
                   [5.556256817028301, -7.025669295257478, 1.7240530742321507],
                   [5.3173007670429975, -6.898939280431394, 1.7278595480033725],
                   [5.046628449981028, -6.753703318879904, 1.725804884872875],
                   [4.803244289601083, -6.620716409453152, 1.726377963879765],
                   [4.822340852273528, -6.379078541501187, 1.7032476446943],
                   [4.830532452723338, -6.144069893351172, 1.7047976672875338],
                   [4.834760563421453, -5.884305796074045, 1.6876475718597206],
                   [5.110719812888194, -6.028142616316405, 1.687525680260671],
                   [5.417740311618597, -6.184558989903391, 1.7124527178431916],
                   [5.385270875729216, -6.438008203433672, 1.712366908533943],
                   [5.355507693509876, -6.661093026054448, 1.729038450873722],
                   [5.07348022798482, -6.513010696655368, 1.726279452092121],
                   [5.090180621637709, -6.283446799878667, 1.7091940453643182]])


Xt = LocallyLinearEmbedding().fit_transform(points)
plt.scatter(Xt[:, 0], Xt[:, 1])
plt.show()


nn = NearestNeighbors().fit(Xt)
distance, index = nn.kneighbors(n_neighbors=4)
for k, ix in enumerate(index):
    plt.figure(figsize=(4, 4))
    plt.scatter(Xt[ix, 0], Xt[ix, 1])
    plt.scatter(Xt[k, 0], Xt[k, 1])
    plt.show()

This approach will not yield perfect results, especially for points at the edges of the underlying grid. And there will be no guarantees for other interior points.
